# Hide Legend from PHPExcel Charts

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel, bar-chart

I have started using `PHPExcel 1.7.9` for creating different types of charts. I want to hide `Legend`. I have tried many possible solutions but coudn't be able to find the exact way. First I tried to empty the first parameter of `PHPExcel_Chart_Legend` like this

```
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend('', NULL, false);
```

It started to show my Legend at right side in vertical position. Then I tried to empty the `Legend` parameter of `PHPExcel_Chart` but it generated an error like follow

```
  // Create the chart
    $chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
                    'chart1', // name
                    $title, // title
                    '', // legend
                    $plotarea, // plotArea
                    true, // plotVisibleOnly
                    0, // displayBlanksAs
                    $xAxisLabel, // xAxisLabel
                    $yAxisLabel // yAxisLabel
    );
```

I have tried to search it out but still not succeeded. Please advice a way so that I can hide legends in my charts.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suppress the legend, simply set it to NULL

```
// Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',      // name
    $title,        // title
    NULL,          // legend
    $plotarea,     // plotArea
    true,          // plotVisibleOnly
    0,             // displayBlanksAs
    $xAxisLabel,   // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel    // yAxisLabel
);
```

Comment: This is what I was needed. +1 . I have asked an other question related to it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086646/create-multi-color-bar-in-phpexcel-charts . Kindly response there too.

Comment: Please have a look on this question too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094890/some-questions-about-phpexcel-charts