# Create multi color bar in PHPExcel Charts

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel

I want to create a bar chart using `PHPExcel` in multi color means every bar can contain multi color as shown below.

[image]

I have searched it out but couldn't be able to find out the solution.

Second question how can I increase width of bar?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a stacked column chart, so you need to set the plotGrouping to PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STACKED

See /Examples/33chartcreate-bar-stacked.php for an example

but set `$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COLUMN);` to stack vertically rathe rthan horizontally

Comment: Seen that file, but don't know how to make a bar as multi color. In that file there is nothing like this

Comment: Each column should show as three different colours to represent the different values in that bar

Comment: Yes asking how can I change color option for each column? Because Haven't found any way to change color and especially like this.

Comment: Actually I want to give color as I like. Is it possible to give color as you like?

Comment: And One thing more how to write on a bar? Means some text on bar?

Comment: Please answer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094890/some-questions-about-phpexcel-charts