# PHPExcel set default Column Width

Tags: phpexcel

Today I had a little problem with excelphp.
I wanted to set the default width of the columns manually and only one single time.

I found a few solutions also here on stackoverflow which suggested to change the value for every single column (e.g. within a loop).

But I wanted to do it with a single command.

Comment: I wish to change the cell height of the entire sheet. Please help to get this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After browsing the source code I found out the following solution:

```
$phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultColumnDimension()
    ->setWidth($myCustomWidth);
```

I hope that this helps anybody else ;)